# convolution with $C^{\infty}$ produces $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

**Problem:** So I have the following function in $\mathbb{R^p}$$$f_{\sigma}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}}f\left(\boldsymbol{z}\right)\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\left|\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}\right|^{2}\right)d\boldsymbol{z}$$ and I would like to show that it infinitely differentiable.  where $f$ is a bounded function with compact support

**Attempted:**
So first notice that $$Df_{\sigma}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{d/2}}\lim_{x\in B,m\left(B\right)\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1}{m\left(B\right)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}}f\left(\boldsymbol{z}\right)\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\left|\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}\right|^{2}\right)d\boldsymbol{z}$$which by rearrange terms on the RHS gives $$\dfrac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{d/2}}\lim_{x\in B,m\left(B\right)\rightarrow0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}}f\left(\boldsymbol{z}\right)\dfrac{1}{m\left(B\right)}\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\left|\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}\right|^{2}\right)d\boldsymbol{z}$$. I think I am supposed to to Dominated Convergence Theorem here. But I don't see what is dominating this function, i.e, the satisfying condition for me to invoke DCT..

Comment: if $K$ is an upper bound for $f$, and $L$ is a *positive* lower bound for the exponential on the support of $f$, then $K/L$ times that exponential or something like that works.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez My question is how do i take care of $1/m(B)$ as this gets small... the stuff inside the integral gets really large as $1/m(B)$ gets really small...so wouldn't that be a problem for us to find a dominating function?

Comment: Well, I really don't know what your operator $D$ is supposed to do or in what way it is related to the differentiability of $f_\sigma$... The function $f_\sigma$ is a differentiable function in the usual sense: just compute its incremental quotient and take the limit, as in Calculus 1.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Can you look that this post? I post a question under.. I don't see why that is uniformly dominated either ,can you explain it to me?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Normally, one would show partial differentiability by showing that one can differentiate (partially) under the integral sign. Then one sees the partial derivatives can again be partially differentiated (again differentiation under the integral sign), ad infinitum. Since $f$ is bounded with compact support, it suffices to note that every polynomial (in $z$) is bounded on the support of $f$, and that differentiating $\exp \left(c\cdot \lvert z-x\rvert^2\right)$ produces poylnomials times the exponential factor.

Comment: @DanielFischer what if I only assume that $f$ is bounded and continuous? will this affect the result?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think it won't since the exponential is going to make everything L1 eventually. Is this right?

Comment: It won't affect the result, you can relax the requirements of $f$ a lot without losing the smoothness of the convolution. But the weaker your assumptions on $f$ are, the more of the burden you need to place on the exponential. If your assumptions on $f$ include compact support, practically none of the exponential's nice properties need to be used. Of course at some point it becomes more economic to prove, if it is not yet known, that the exponential belongs to the Schwartz space, and then you see that you only need $f$ to be a tempered distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to prove the following first (I'll retrict myself to functions on $\mathbb R$)

> If $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and has compact support and $g\in C^1(\mathbb R)$, then the function $h$ defined so that $h(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(z)g(x-z)dz$ is in $C^1(\mathbb R)$ and in fact $h'(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(z)g'(x-z)dz$.

You can do this by showing that for all $x_0\in\mathbb R$ the limit of the quotient $\frac{h(x)-h(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ as $x\to x_0$ exists and is equal to the expected thing. You will use the DCT to do this.

After that, you can prove by induction that

> if $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and has compact support and $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, then the function $h$ defined so that $h(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(z)g(x-z)dz$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

and give an explicit formula for the derivatives, if you want.